# Apache Spark: Streaming without HDFS checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I'm implementing a Spark job which makes use of **reduceByKeyAndWindow**, therefore I need to add checkpointing.

From Spark's website I see that:

> Checkpointing can be enabled by setting a directory in a fault-tolerant, reliable file system (e.g., HDFS, S3, etc.) to which the checkpoint information will be saved.

My application is just for academic purposes, thus I don't want to set an HDFS for checkpointing but just a local file. Doing so in MacOS works fine (setting a temporary dir as checkpoint dir), the problem comes when doing it in Windows, which throws an exception for permissions.

I already tried starting eclipse as administrator and creating the directory manually setting **setWritable**, **setReadable** and **setExecutable** to **true**. Any hint on how to overcome the problem in Windows?

Thanks!

**Update** Here's my code and exception. Just to clarify again, it works fine in Mac but not in Windows.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("testApp").setMaster("local[2]");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(ctx, new Duration(1000));
jsc.checkpoint(Files.createTempDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "pool-7-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:639)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:905)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:886)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:783)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:772)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointWriter$CheckpointWriteHandler.run(Checkpoint.scala:135)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what exception do you exactly get? could you show us your code?

Comment: Updated with code + stack trace for exception

Comment: Why do you want to enable checkpointing at all?

Comment: Stateful operations such as reduceByKeyAndWindow require it

Comment: Hi @sergi123, I'm currently having this same error. I am using Mac and a standalone version of spark. I would be happy if you could help me with this error or point me to some resources that I can use. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the latest Hadoop libraries to my project.

If using Maven, the following set of dependencies do the trick.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can solve this problem as following

- Download [winutils.exe](https://github.com/srccodes/hadoop-common-2.2.0-bin/blob/master/bin/winutils.exe) to a folder say MY_UTILS/bin
- Create an environment variable HADOOP_HOME and point it to MY_UTILS